# Embed Flash Transparent FLV

Tags: html, flash, embed, flv, transparent

I am trying to embed a flash movie (.flv) into a webpage with a transparent background.

Requirements:
- Flv runs in transparent mode - I must be able to view html contents below.
- Movie does not auto play
- Movie is contained in a div and positionend absolutely using CSS
- No video controls or overlays, you shouldn't know it's an flv
- On load Movie is hidden
- Using jQuery, I click an image link to show and play the video, clicking it again stops and hides the video - vice versa

I have tried using Longtail Video Player with swfobject.js and javascript controls but no joy. Video is not transparent and controls with a click to play still feature.

Am I overcomplicating what appears to be quite a simple task.

I happy to explore any implementation.

Adobe flash embed parameters have been set correctly and wmode = transparent.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers
Paul

Comment: Can you post some of the HTML embed code or swfobject config code? Also, you don't have a bg set to the holder div with css, do you? Might just be an issue with the video player you're using. Many video player components come with their own controls and a default background, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you a transparent overlay in flash. Its a pretty good set of code.

http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/

SWFObject Examples

The example given above is what you need for the bare bones use of SWFObject, but what if you want to use some of the other parameters the Flash plug-in has to offer? SWFObject makes it very easy to add any extra parameter you may need. The examples below are a number of different methods you may wish to use to embed your Flash content.

A simple example adding a few extra parameters

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var so = new SWFObject("movie.swf", "mymovie", "200", "100%", "7", "#336699");
so.addParam("quality", "low");
so.addParam("wmode", "transparent");
so.addParam("salign", "t");
so.write("flashcontent");
</script>
<div id="flashcontent"><!--put a place holder image in here.--></div>
```

http://blog.deconcept.com/swfobject/

EDIT:
THANKS TO Unreality: There has been an update in the code library you can now access it here: http://www.code.google.com/p/swfobject

Comment: your example provided used swfobject 1.5 , which will be different from the most updated swfobject 2+ from http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/ . Good tool and good answer tho :)

Comment: Thanks for the update i have not used it in a while. I will be sure to check out the updated link though ;)