# How to play FLV video on website with transparent background

Tags: web, background, flv, transparent

I have a FLV video made and want to put it onto website.
Basically this is what I am looking for: http://www.bellmedia.com/

I came across this question but the answer is referring to .swf object.
[Embed Flash Transparent FLV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827006/embed-flash-transparent-flv)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [longtailvideo](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player)? It's awesome player I've ever used.

Comment: Hi, after some search on FW player forum and it does support transparent background playing on website, with some skin customisation. However, I go with the other easier option: http://www.transparentplayer.com/ . It is not free but FW player is not free either. Thanks